Should we consider GeneralizedRCNNTransform while selecting anchor sizes in Faster R-CNN
I am training a Faster R-CNN on pytorch. The size of my images are 512x512 pixels. Until now, I computed the anchor sizes based on the sizes of my bounding box annotations on the 512x512 pixel images. But I saw in the implementation of Faster R-CNN in pytorch, that any input image is pre-processed by torchvision with the GeneralizedRCNNTransform class. Consequently, the image size after this processing step changes.
My question is: are the anchors also pre-processed? Or should I set the anchor sizes in correspondence to the new sizes of my bounding box annotations in the transformed/pre-processed image?
When I adapted the anchors to the transformed image. I got slightly better results. But I am not sure whether it was coincidence.
